# change maximum length of file upload in php

Tags: php, linux, php-5.3, ini, maxlength

I have a form with multiple image upload in php. My hosting is a linux server. My problem is that, when I upload more than 5 images, the file name size increase, because I am encrypting the name of the images,

> By default my server support 260 length file name only. I need to
>   increase the size of the file path.

When I googled, everyone was preferring for changing the php.ini file. But

> I can't edit my php.ini file because I am using a shared server. So
>   that I need to change it via my base php code.

Can I do it in any way?

Comment: and what encryption name you use? Maybe you can make it shorter.

Comment: I am using md5, and it is fixed as 32 character... :(

Comment: And your save files as `<md5_hash>_<old_name>` or what? How long is you current base path

Comment: You can add a second php.ini file inside your project which will override the global php.ini